# Error propagation in expression with trigonometric functions

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

In a physics lab inclined plane experiment, I am calculating the kinetic friction $\mu$ using the formula:

$$\mu = \tan\theta - (a/g)\sec\theta$$

Here $a$ is the acceleration and $\theta$ is the angle made by the inclined plane with the horizontal.
For the given uncertainties $\Delta\theta$ and $\Delta a$, I calculate the uncertainty  $\Delta\mu$  in $\mu$. Following is the formula I get for the uncertainty in $ \mu$:

$$\Delta \mu = \sqrt{\left[\left(\sec^2\theta - \dfrac{a}{g}\tan\theta\sec\theta\right)\Delta\theta\right]^2 + \left[\sec\theta \dfrac{\Delta a}{g} \right]^2  }$$

Here are the values for the two trials:

$\theta = 27.48^\circ, \Delta\theta = 0.16^\circ (0.58\%), a= 1.96\textrm{m/s$^{2}$} , \Delta a = 0.11\textrm{m/s$^{2}$} (5.61\%), \mu = 0.29,  \Delta\mu = 0.013 (4.42\%) $

and

$\theta = 52.17^\circ, \Delta\theta = 0.25^\circ (0.48\%), a= 5.80\textrm{m/s$^{2}$} , \Delta a = 0.35\textrm{m/s$^{2}$} (6.03\%), \mu= 0.32 , \Delta\mu = 0.059 (18.07\%) $

Since the $\Delta \theta$'s are too small in comparison to $\Delta a $'s , I expect the $\Delta\mu$'s to be close to $\Delta a$. This is coming out to be true for the first case when the angle is small ($4.42\%$ vs $5.61\%$). However for the second case when the angle is larger, the uncertainty in $\mu$ is coming out to be three times the uncertainty in the acceleration ($18\%$ vs $6\%$)!

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong here?

I agree that the uncertainty does depend on the angle here but is it safe to say that the error propagation in trigonometric functions seems to be overestimating the experimental errors?

Is there any other way I can calculate the error propagation in $\mu$ here?

Comment: Could you have accidentally computed trigonometric functions of $52.17$ radians instead?

Comment: @J.G. all angles are converted to radians and computed. AFAIK, there is no mistake in the calculation. It is $\tan\theta\sec\theta$ term which is pushing it higher.

Comment: Then I see no reason to think you've made a mistake. Since these functions are unbounded, they can give large contributions to the error.